# Why is flask's jsonify method slow?

Tags: python, json, performance, api, flask

I'm writing an API in flask that returns json.  Each flask function is of the form

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/getdata')
def get_data():
    data = load_data_as_dict()
    return jsonify(data)
```

If I return a large amount of data, a call to this function takes around 1.7 seconds.  However, if I do this:

```
from flask import Response
@app.route('/getdata')
def get_data():
    data = load_data_as_dict()
    data_as_str = json.dumps(data)
    return Response(response=data_as_str, status=200, mimetype="application/json"
```

...the function completes in around .05 seconds.

Can anyone tell me why `jsonify` is so much slower?  Is there anything wrong with returning a raw Flask response instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is: it has a lot to do with indentation and making a `pretty` json dump. Here's the method definition (I stripped the comments to save space, full code can be found [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/json.py)) :

```
def jsonify(*args, **kwargs):
    indent = None
    separators = (',', ':')

    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
        indent = 2
        separators = (', ', ': ')

    if args and kwargs:
        raise TypeError('jsonify() behavior undefined when passed both args and kwargs')
    elif len(args) == 1:  # single args are passed directly to dumps()
        data = args[0]
    else:
        data = args or kwargs

    return current_app.response_class(
        (dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators), '\n'),
        mimetype=current_app.config['JSONIFY_MIMETYPE']
    )
```

`dumps` wraps `simplejson.dumps` if the module is available, otherwise it uses `json.dumps`.

Comment: Its true, i tried it. If you redefine jsonify and jsut remove indent, it will work way faster. In my test time changed from 17s to 0.1s, 170 times!

Answer (score 7):

`jsonify()` just wraps `json.dumps()`. However, depending upon the config of your Flask app and the Flask version that you're using, it may pass `indent=2` and `separators=(', ', ': ')` to `json.dumps`. (See the docs on pretty-printing at https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html if you're unfamiliar with these arguments).

Passing these arguments slows down `json.dumps` dramatically. Using the 181MB `citylots.json` file from https://github.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json as sample data, these pretty-printing arguments increase `json.dumps()`'s runtime from 7 seconds to 31 seconds on my MacBook Pro:

```
>>> import time 
>>> import json
>>> citylots = json.load(open('citylots.json'))
>>> start = time.time(); x = json.dumps(citylots); print(time.time() - start)
7.165302753448486
>>> x = None
>>> start = time.time(); x = json.dumps(citylots, indent=2, separators=(', ', ': ')); print(time.time() - start)
31.19125771522522
```

As of Flask 1.0, this costly pretty-printing will happen if *either*:

- You've explicitly set `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` to `True` in your app's config (it's `False` by default), OR
- You're running your app in debug mode

(You can see these conditions in the Flask 1.0.2 code at https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.2/flask/json/__init__.py#L309.)

If you are using Flask >=1.0 and have the (probably unusual) need to disable the pretty-printing *even in debug* mode, you can always implement your own `jsonify` by copying and pasting the built-in `jsonify`'s definition and deleting all the pretty-printing logic:

```
from flask import current_app
from json import dumps

def jsonify(*args, **kwargs):
    if args and kwargs:
        raise TypeError('jsonify() behavior undefined when passed both args and kwargs')
    elif len(args) == 1:  # single args are passed directly to dumps()
        data = args[0]
    else:
        data = args or kwargs

    return current_app.response_class(
        dumps(data) + '\n',
        mimetype=current_app.config['JSONIFY_MIMETYPE']
    )
```

If you're in a version Flask *prior* to 1.0, then pretty-printing instead happens if both:

- You *haven't* explicitly set `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` to `False` in you app's config (it's `True` by default), AND
- The current request is not an XHR request

In those older versions, there is never any need to redefine `jsonify` to eliminate the pretty-printing, since you can just do:

```
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = False
```

(Alternatively, if you're using a pre-1.0 version of Flask and only want to disable the pretty-printing in production, then there's no need to change your code; instead, just upgrade to the latest version of Flask.)

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while to figure out,  but Flask `jsonify` sets the `sort_keys` argument on the encoder and it seems it defaults to `True`.

Adding:

```
JSON_SORT_KEYS = False
```

To the configuration gave me a factor 7 speed up for larger JSON structures.

Comment: Oh, wow, that's a pretty big deal that I totally missed in my answer! I might update mine accordingly.

Comment: Be careful with this as it could cause lots of unnecessary cache-misses due to different ordering of the same data.

Comment: Same with debug mode ... pretty big object takes 2.5 seconds to serialize for me in debug mode (because pretty-printing), and a mere 50ms without.